# Inline div with negative left positioning, cannot occupy some part of its parent div

Tags: html, css

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6xm3303q/) issue, that if I change the `width` of `.info` to something bigger than `120px` then it will push the red `div` down. It seems that the space, represented with the pink colour, cannot be occupied by the red `div`.

For now, I suspect that's because I put `left: -60px` on `.info` and `.vertical_shadow`.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 480px;
  height: 120px;
}
img, div {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: black;
}
.vertical_shadow {
  left: -60px;
  background-color: green;
}
.info {
  left: -60px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.memo {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="photo">
  <div class="vertical_shadow"></div>
  <div class="info"></div>
  <div class="memo"></div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to move the red `div` beside the blue `div`, then expand the `width` of the blue `div` to a number greater than `120px`?

Comment: You're right.. You should put that on the answer, so I can tick your answer..

Comment: try to make as absolute

Comment: Added answer as requested.

Answer (score 3):

`relative` positioning doesn't **actually** move the element. It moves the place where it's rendered *visually*. The space where it *was* is reserved for it by the browser. You might try negative margins instead.

This demo explains that :

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/IuLfJ)

I think this is what you were trying to achieve but it's a little unclear.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 480px;
  height: 120px;
  z-index: -11;
}
img,
div {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: black;
}
.vertical_shadow {
  margin-left: -60px;
  background-color: green;
}
.info {
  margin-left: -60px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.memo {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="photo" />
  <div class="vertical_shadow"></div>
  <div class="info"></div>
  <div class="memo"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="photo">
    <div class="vertical_shadow">
    </div>
    <div class="info">
    </div>
    <div class="memo">
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    .container{
        position: relative;
        background-color: pink;
        width: 480px;
        height: 120px;
    }
    img, div{
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        background-color: black;
    }
    .vertical_shadow{
        position: absolute;
        left: -60px;
        background-color: green;
    }
    .info{
        left: -60px;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: blue;
    }
    .memo{
        position: absolute;
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```